# Dell Inspiron 1150 - Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, inspiron

I have an old Dell Inspiron 1150 .... Celeron 2.60GHz .... 1GB of memory
512MBDDR PC2700 X2

Purchased in 2004.  It was the family laptop for years.  Now it's become the TurboTax computer with no other real purpose.  Already copied needed files to an external hard drive.

Waiting for delivery of Ubuntu:
Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr Desktop 64 bit Live DVD/Install Disc.

Will 14.04 work? I want to do a single install.  Want XP wiped off the unit entirely.  The Dell is so larded-up with unnecessary stuff that I want a fresh start.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similarish old Inspiron which works fine. However, you may want to consider Lubuntu instead: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu

I'm not sure what graphics your Inspiron has, but with a relatively low amount of memory and a slowish graphics (I'm guessing), the "lightweight" version of Ubuntu would probably be more responsive for you.

Comment: Here's the info I got from the Dell:                            INTEL(R) EXTREME GRAPHICS 2 FOR MOBILE REPORT
Driver Version:  6.14.10.4396
Operating System:  Windows XP* Professional, 
DirectX* Version:  9.0
Physical Memory:  1022 MB
Minimum Graphics Memory: 1 MB
Maximum Graphics Memory: 64 MB
Graphics Memory in Use: 5 MB
Processor:  x86
Processor Speed:  2597 MHZ
Vendor ID:  8086
Device ID:  3582

Comment: Should I look for something more specific?

Comment: That's useful. I am pretty sure it *will* work, but I think you may find it a bit slow. If you have a Trusty boot disc, you could try it in Live mode to see how you get on (though the experience will be slower still).

Comment: Just ordered:  Lubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr Desktop 32 bit CD .... appreciate the detailed explanation.

Comment: No problem. Hope you get on okay with it!